Build Azure Container Instance from Docker Compose
I'm newbee to the Docker world.
I have created the following docker-compose.yaml.
version: "3.9"
services:
  CreditApp:
    container_name: CreditApp
    image: xyz.azurecr.io/creditapp
    network_mode: bridge
    build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "8000:8000"
     - "1433:1433"
    secrets:
      - source: db-secret
        target: /opt/scr/secrets/db/db.secrets
        mode: 0400
    volumes:
      - ./db.config:/opt/scr/config/db/db.config
secrets:
  db-secret:
    file: ./db.secrets

When using in my local Docker everything works fine (started with docker compose up --build)
In the next step the image is pushed to Azure Container Registry.
Having image on ACR I'd like to build Azure Container Instance. ACI is built but it doesn't contain db.secrets and db.config files.
How to add secrets and volumes definitions to ACI with AZ CLI?

I finally understood the process and was able to build ACI with secrets and volumes.
For reference:
az container create --resource-group rgname --name creditapp --image xyz.azurecr.io/creditapp:latest --dns-name-label appname --ip-address Public  --ports 80 8080 --protocol TCP --restart-policy OnFailure --registry-login-server xyz.azurecr.io --registry-username username --registry-password $TOKEN --azure-file-volume-account-key keyvalue --azure-file-volume-account-name accountname --azure-file-volume-mount-path /opt/scr/config/db --azure-file-volume-share-name scr --secrets db.secrets="value" --secrets-mount-path /opt/scr/secrets/db

